# Spring Integration Wiretap and Exceptions

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm using Spring Integration and have set a wiretap on a channel so that I can log some data. One concern I have though is that if an Exception is thrown during the logging, the message is not passed along the channel that I am snooping on.

I would have thought that the purpose of a wiretap was to allow me to listen in on the message without making myself known, but this appears not to be the case.

Other than me wrapping the whole thing up in a try/catch block, is there any way to ignore exceptions in the wiretap ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your configuration? Typically you get to specify what is your error-channel. If you don't specify one, it would land up in a special channel called errorChannel (you don't have to declare this channel as it is already available to you).